# java.io.FileNotFoundException when adding new venues

Tags: android, foursquare

I've been trying to use the [venues/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add) api as in the following codes:

```
    private static final String FOURSQUARE_API = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2"
    public  void addVenue(final String address, final String name) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(FOURSQUARE_API
                        + "/venues/add"
                        + "?name=" + address + PREFIX + name
                        + "&ll=" + mLL
                        + "&oauth_token=" + mAccessToken
                        + "&v=" + mVersion);
                Log.d(TAG, "opening url " + url);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.connect();

                String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                JSONObject resp = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                JSONObject venue = resp.getJSONObject("venue");
                String venueId = venue.getString("id");
                String name = venue.getString("name");
                JSONObject location = venue.getJSONObject("location");
                String lat = location.getString("lat");
                String lng = location.getString("lng");
                Log.d(TAG, "venueId: " + venueId + "; " + "name: " + name + "; " + "latitude: " + lat + "longitude:" + lng);    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
    private  String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String str  = "";

    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }

        str = sb.toString();
    }

    return str;
}
```

`mLL` is user's current position and `address + PREFIX + name` is user-specified name
  I know if I attempt to add two similar names I may get an error as stated [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add). However, what I encounter is a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` which makes it impossible to resubmit. I've successfully added new venues with distinguished names. So what is this exception about?

EDIT: here's the complete Error info:

```
 12-23 10:17:41.042: W/System.err(377): java.io.FileNotFoundException:   https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/add?name=LikeLouclassroomB222&ll=31.2297,121.4033&oauth_token=CONS3IBOUEH2YTBA3IMNI3YH4CWSUKQ500QSOXJZQ23LXBH1&v=20111223
 12-23 10:17:41.042: W/System.err(377):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
 12-23 10:17:41.062: W/System.err(377):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
 12-23 10:17:41.072: W/System.err(377):     at com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.study.FoursquareAPI$1.run(FoursquareAPI.java:56)
```

`(FoursquareAPI.java:56)` => `String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());`

p.s. I really need to add venues with similar names.

Comment: Can you post the exception you are getting? I'm not sure what is throwing that, given your code.

Comment: =Todd. you should check to make sure you're not getting a 409 -- resource conflict (see https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/responses for details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened the code of HttpURLConnectionImpl that throws the exception.

That exception is thrown if the response code from the server is >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST (=400)
(By the way, this is the only thing that throws a FileNotFoundException in HttpURLConnectionImpl)

Since you did not give us the exact response code, as akdotcom suggested look at the [responses that foursquare can return](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/responses) , use [getErrorStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29) to get the data that the foursquare server returned. It should clarify the issue..